# How to delete all sessions and cookies

Tags: codeigniter, session, cookies

I'm wondering if is there any way to remove all domain site cookies and sessions params.

somenthing like `$this->session->destroy();`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$this->session->sess_destroy()
```

Comment: yep it works but i would like to remove also session keys, it clears values of the session keys, $seesion['somenthing'] = false while i would like to remove/delete the $session['somenthing'] namespace

Comment: This seems to not remove all cookies as well. Does it only remove `SESSION` variables?

Comment: cookies and session are different. I'm not sure how codeigniter handles it though.

Comment: This  not remove all cookies. Just destroy the session.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note for applications where post destroying session, you want user to land on the index page where that point forward is taken care of the function, use bellow,

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect('');
```

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter 4, If you want to delete all your session data along with index/key then you can use this:

```
$this->session->destroy();
```